# Why can't EMR Notebook can't connect to its cluster when running as the AWS account owner

Tags: amazon-emr

I have created an AWS EMR cluster and notebook using default settings.

When I open the notebook, the kernel won't launch.  I get the message "Workspace is not attached to cluster".

- The cluster is in a "Ready" state.
- None of the kernels work (Python, Spark, PySPark).
- The error occurs using both Jupyter Labs or Jupyter.
- I switched to a different AWS account where I had never run EMR and created a notebook.  I requested that a cluster be created.  AWS launched a cluster, but gave the same error when I launched a notebook.

**A clue**

I looked at the log files created by a cluster where the notebook failed.

In the log file `https://aws-logs-***.s3.amazonaws.com/elasticmapreduce/j-3SOK08VFSQDPO/node/i-04af0a3d2d6d96cac/daemons/emr-on-cluster-env/gateway.log.gz`, I found the following:

```
Jupyter Enterprise Gateway 2.1.0 is available at http://127.0.0.1:9547
User 'root' is not authorized to start kernel 'Python 3'. Ensure KERNEL_USERNAME is set to an appropriate value and retry the request.
User 'root' is not authorized to start kernel 'PySpark'. Ensure KERNEL_USERNAME is set to an appropriate value and retry the request.
```

**How I got the notebook kernel to work**

Per the Stackoverflow post [Notebooks on EMR (AWS): Failed to start kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951352/notebooks-on-emr-aws-failed-to-start-kernel), I switched from using the root AWS account, to an [IAM user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html).  This worked with EMR 6.5.0.

**My question**

What changed when I launched the cluster with an IAM account?  How could I have figured out that using the root user is the problem?

*EMR is a black box to me.  Thanks in advance for helping me understand the inner workings of this amazing technology.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the key issue:

```
User 'root' is not authorized to start kernel 'Python 3'. Ensure KERNEL_USERNAME is set to an appropriate value and retry the request.
User 'root' is not authorized to start kernel 'PySpark'. Ensure KERNEL_USERNAME is set to an appropriate value and retry the request.
```

You need to create a normal IAM account, with EMR permission, login with that user, and start the notebook from there. Your main AWS account is root account. I talked to the AWS support and got my notebook running that way.